# Deploying Flask app on Elastic Beanstalk: No module named 'application'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Got a Flask app that has the Flask `application` initialization in the main module's `__init__.py` file, much like the Flask docs has [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/) (except I'm **not** using an app factory type function)

```
myapp/
  myapp/
    __init__.py  # application = Flask(__name__) is here
    static/
    templates/
    ...
  requirements.txt
```

Local environment runs fine with `flask run` when `FLASK_APP` is set to `myapp`.

My attempt with the Beanstalk deployment is via `eb-cli` and I have the `FLASK_APP` set in `.ebextensions/options.yml` like so:

```
option_settings:
 aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
   LC_ALL: en_US.utf8
   FLASK_APP: myapp
   FLASK_ENV: production
```

Then I'm running:

```
eb init -p python-3.7 myapp --region us-east-1
eb create myapp-env
```

It seems to launch fine, but the environment becomes degraded, I get a 502 and the logs show that the Flask app does not launch correctly due to `No module named 'application'`

I was under the impression that setting `FLASK_APP` would be enough to locate the Flask app instance.

How do I deploy a Flask app via Elastic Beanstalk in this context? Do I need to further specify the entry-point somehow?

Comment: I think you have to customize `WSGIPath` as your application is not `application.py`. You can use [aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-python) in order to do so.

Comment: Any idea what that should look like exactly? I'm trying it with `WSGIPath: application`.

Comment: I would start with renaming/refactoring your code (if possible) to use `application.py` instead of `__init_.py`, to confirm that this is actually the issue. `application.py` should be in root of your folder, not subfolders. Also `.ebextensions/options.yml` is incorrect. The extension should be `.config`. If you confirm this, then you know where to concentrate the efforts to solve the issue. Not sure how to use `__init__.py`. Would have to try-and-see how to use it in  `WSGIPath`.

Comment: The answer is `WSGIPath: myapp:application`. You want to put this as an answer? I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I would like to provide an answer  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using custom flask application path. By default, EB expects the application to be located in  `application.py` file.

To **solution** was to specify the custom path using `WSGIPath` in  [aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-python) option:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: myapp:application
```